# Chunking >100mb file on Flask

Tags: flask, file-upload, chunking

I would like to upload files between 100-200mb using Flask on PythonAnywhere (which has a 100mb upload limit). I am trying to implement chunking but am still getting a 413 Request Entity Too Large error and am unsure why. I assume it has to do with using open(large_file) but am unsure how to get around this. Any help would be apprecaited?

All the files in /home/zweiss124/mysite/files that end in .fastq are 100-200mb.

```
def read_in_chunks(file_object, chunk_size=10000):
    while True:
        data = file_object.read(chunk_size)
        if not data:
            break
        yield data

def get_uploaded_files():
    global uploaded_files
    uploaded_files = []
    global num_chunks
    num_chunks = []
    os.chdir("/home/zweiss124/mysite/files")
    #for file in shared_dict["filenames"]:
    for file in glob.glob("*.fastq"):
        f = open(file)
        index = 0
        offset = 0
        headers = {}
        all_chunks = ''
        ind_num_chunks = 0
        for chunk in read_in_chunks(f):
            offset = index + len(chunk)
            headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/octet-stream'
            index = offset
            all_chunks+=chunk
            ind_num_chunks+=1
        num_chunks.append(ind_num_chunks)
        uploaded_files.append(all_chunks.split("\n")[:4*shared_dict["num_to_upload"]])
    return uploaded_files, num_chunks
```

Comment: You are chunking the writes to the disk, the file that is sent in the request is not affected by that. You will need to break the file into multiple files on the client before sending them individually to the server.

Comment: This makes sense - is there a documented example of this anywhere?